# pycafe installation on conda fails in MacBook Air Catalina

Tags: python, macos, conda, macos-catalina

I use MacBook Air, with `catalina OS`. The `conda` version I use is `4.9.2`.

I am trying to install `pycafe` with `conda` using the following syntax in my homebrew window:

```
conda install -c paulscherrerinstitute pycafe
```

And I get the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pycafe

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/paulscherrerinstitute/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/paulscherrerinstitute/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Can you please help on how to install `pycafe`?

Comment: Can you give more details on what `pycafe` is and how you found it? The channel you are attempting to install from is a user channel and generally should not be trusted unless you know/trust the user. Moreover, that package is over three years old, only for Python 3.5 (which the user did not properly configure in the dependencies), and only built for **linux-64** platform. I.e., very unlikely you could use it.

Comment: I got this download reference from Anaconda url: https://anaconda.org/paulscherrerinstitute/pycafe. pycafe is a Cython-based API that provides EPICS connectivity to Python through the CAFE library.

Comment: As merv has said, that package is only available for linux (which is also mentioned on the anaconda website you have linked), hence your error message

Answer (score 0):

### Package Unavailable for OS X

As mentioned in the comments, this particular package is only available through a user channel and they had only built it for the **linux-64** platform and Python 3.5. If you're keen on avoiding having to compile this yourself (and I should note that the version build is still the latest), then I'd suggest going through Docker to build and host the environment.

### Alternative: Docker Container

I put together a basic Dockerfile and YAML as a starter, but I'd expect there may be some additional configuration (e.g., setting environmental variables) that is needed.

**pycafe.yaml**

```yaml
name: pycafe
channels:
  - paulscherrerinstitute
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.5
  - pycafe
  - cafe
  - numpy
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ROM continuumio/miniconda3

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

# Install PyCafe
COPY pycafe.yaml .
RUN conda env create -f pycafe.yaml -n pycafe \
  && conda config --set auto_activate_base false \
  && sed -i "s/conda activate base/conda activate pycafe/" ~/.bashrc \
  && conda clean -a -y
```

Placing both of these in a directory, one can build the Docker image with

```
docker build -t "pycafe:1.3.0" .
```

Then one could launch a Python session with

```
docker run -it pycafe:1.3.0 bash
python
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Merv for your comments :)